# How to disable data binding observables for a while

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I want to disable data binding observables for a while, so that I can change a `Switch` check status without notifying its listener. Listener is attached in Layout in `onCheckChange`, so it is fired when I manually change checked status in Model.

Comment: Can you share a code snippet of how you're notifying your changes?

Comment: Can you share a code snippet of how you're notifying your changes?